# accessing profile property through resource filtering

Tags: java, maven

I have this pom structure and I am trying to access property `hub.p`, which is set in
`build-helper-maven-plugin`, which is inside profile and stores port number . Port is assigned as I get on console
something like this `Reserved port 59831 for hub.p` . I am unable to access this through resource filtering through another property `hub.port` , which is defined in properties section

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
...

<build>
 ....
           <resources>
                     <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>

                        </resource>
            </resources>  
  ...
</build>
        <properties>
        
             <hub.port>${hub.p}</hub.port>
        </properties>

       <dependencies>
        ...
      </dependencies>

  <profiles>
  
        <profile>
            <id>acceptanceTests</id>
        <build>
           ...
            <plugins>
             ....
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                <execution>
                 <id>reserve-server-port</id>
                   <goals>
                   <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                  </goals>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                 <configuration>
                  <portNames>
                     <portName>hub.p</portName>
              </portNames>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
      ....
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project
```

in `src/test/resources` , I have `pom.properties` property file , which has this

```
hubPort=${hub.port}
```

And I am accessing property like this

```
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("pom.properties"); 
            properties.load(inputStream);
            String portForHub = properties.getProperty("hubPort");
            System.out.println("hubport..."+portForHub);
```

But it prints

`hubport...${hub.port}`

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531832/maven-resources-filtering) ,but I am not able to access the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked for me. Instead of resource filtering, I passed `${hub.p}` directly to `<systemPropertyVariables>` of failsafe plugin, so it can be captured in tests.

In failsafe plugin config

```
                 <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                     <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                       <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <hub.port>${hub.p}</hub.port>                         
                      </systemPropertyVariables>
                  </configuration>
```

And then in tests

`System.getProperty("hub.port")`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486920/how-to-get-port-number-from-jetty-maven-plugin#)  helped